# SQL Server database mirroring server address connection error

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

I'm configuring database mirroring using SQL Server. Two Windows Server 2008 R2 machines with SQL Server.

1. Principal server - took full backup with transactional backup
2. Mirror server - restored back up with no recovery

Configured the principal and mirror server details,

[image]

It is successful.

[image]

While starting the mirroring, I get the following error:

1. I have enabled my ports in windows firewall.
2. I have changed my server network address but no results.
3. I have checked below queries to check the endpoint status all looks fine in both the servers,

Query:

```
SELECT type_desc, port 
FROM sys.tcp_endpoints

SELECT state_desc 
FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints

SELECT role 
FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints

SELECT 
    EP.name, SP.STATE,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(38), suser_name(SP.grantor_principal_id)) AS GRANTOR,
    SP.TYPE AS PERMISSION,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(46),suser_name(SP.grantee_principal_id)) AS GRANTEE
FROM 
    sys.server_permissions SP, sys.endpoints EP
WHERE 
    SP.major_id  = EP.endpoint_id
ORDER BY  
    Permission, grantor, grantee
```

Please anyone help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please i just ensured that i followed this query to validate the endpoints from this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2464/configure-sql-server-database-mirroring-using-ssms/